# Plucking Multiple Properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

I am trying to create an array from an object in AngularJS to use for ui-bootstrap's typeahead.

I am able to pluck a single value out of the object ('Batman') but I need to be able to combine several properties to create a new array element ('Batman (Wayne, Bruce)). I tried `$scope.heroList = _.pluck($scope.heroes, 'name' + '(' + 'lname' + ', ' + 'fname' + ')' );` but got all nulls.

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mAY4PsF1LS8xDynjKPl7?p=preview).

I need a final array that looks like this:

```
$scope.heroList = ['Batman (Wayne, Bruce]', 'Daredevil (Murdoch, Jack'), ... ];
```

Here is my javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('MainController', function($scope){

  $scope.heroes = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Iron Man',
      fname: 'Tony',
      lname: 'Stark',
      location: 'Stark Tower',
      comic: 'Marvel'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Batman',
      fname: 'Bruce',
      lname: 'Wayne',
      location: 'Bat Cave',
      comic: 'DC'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Superman',
      fname: 'Clark',
      lname: 'Kent',
      location: 'Metroplis',
      comic: 'DC'
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Daredevil',
      fname: 'Jack',
      lname: 'Murdock',
      location: 'Court Room',
      comic: 'Marvel'
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: 'Flash',
      fname: 'Barry',
      lname: 'Allen',
      location: 'Speedline',
      comic: 'DC'
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      name: 'Hulk',
      fname: 'Bruce',
      lname: 'Banner',
      location: 'Labratory',
      comic: 'Marvel'
    },
    {
      id: 7,
      name: 'Hawkeye',
      fname: 'Clint',
      lname: 'Barton',
      location: 'Nest',
      comic: 'Marvel'
    },
    {
      id: 8,
      name: 'Thor',
      fname: 'Donald',
      lname: 'Blake',
      location: 'Asgard',
      comic: 'Marvel'
    }
  ];

  $scope.heroList = _.pluck($scope.heroes, 'name');
  //$scope.heroList = _.pluck($scope.heroes, 'name' + '(' + 'lname' + ', ' + 'fname' + ')' );

}); // end MainController
```

Comment: I'd use `collect`/`map` for this instead of `pluck` as it's more canonical, IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use callback method.

Use

```
$scope.heroList = _.pluck($scope.heroes, function(elm){
    return elm.name + '(' + elm.lname + ', ' + elm.fname + ')';
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/1ML7Mmsanz0gizRTtfc9?p=preview)

Also I would recommend you to use [`_.map()`](http://lodash.com/docs#map)

```
$scope.heroList = _.map($scope.heroes, function(elm){
    return elm.name + '(' + elm.lname + ', ' + elm.fname + ')';
});
```

[*DEMO with map*](http://plnkr.co/edit/w4s3jfZ4nejniLNgnfIY?p=preview)

Comment: I am quite new to lodash and didn't know there were callbacks ... cool and while I don't know why using _.map() is better, I changed to use it ... THANKS!!!

Comment: Why is map better?

Answer (score 1):

Try using typeahead's "typeahead-input-formatter" artribute, you can pass a callback to it for formatting the final selected value