# Trying to get a unique list of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I have a collection of objects

```
var array = 
[
    {"category":"A", "categoryname":"somename", key: 1, description: "something"}, 
    {"category":"A", "categoryname":"somename", key: 1, description: "something"}, 
    {"category":"B", "categoryname": "somename", key: 1, description: "something"}
    {"category":"B", "categoryname": "somename", key: 3, description: "something"}
    {"category":"C", "categoryname": "somename", key: 2, description: "something"}
    {"category":"C", "categoryname": "somename", key: 2, description: "something"}
]
```

that have 4 values (category, categoryname, key, description) and I need to loop through it and get a unique list of objects based on the category. But I want to return the unique list with 2 preoperties and not just one. If I use

```
_.uniq(_.pluck(array,"category"))
```

this gives me what I want except I need the categoryname as well as the category. Is this possible?

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: [ ["A", "somename"],["B","somename"],["C","somename"] ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of questions on the same use case already.

[Plucking Multiple Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25527607/plucking-multiple-properties)

[Removing duplicate objects with Underscore for Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923890/removing-duplicate-objects-with-underscore-for-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `$.unique()`, `Array.prototype.map()`, `JSON.stringify()`, `JSON.parse()`

```js
var array = [{
  "category": "A",
  "categoryname": "somename",
  key: 1,
  description: "something"
}, {
  "category": "A",
  "categoryname": "somename",
  key: 1,
  description: "something"
}, {
  "category": "B",
  "categoryname": "somename",
  key: 1,
  description: "something"
}, {
  "category": "B",
  "categoryname": "somename",
  key: 3,
  description: "something"
}, {
  "category": "C",
  "categoryname": "somename",
  key: 2,
  description: "something"
}, {
  "category": "C",
  "categoryname": "somename",
  key: 2,
  description: "something"
}];

var res = $.unique(array.map(function(el) {
  return JSON.stringify([el.category, el.categoryname])
})).map(JSON.parse);

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```